# Normal Family of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm looking for a version of proof of the Fundamental Normality Test and the last part of it states:

> A family of **analytic or meromorphic** functions $A$ is normal if
>   $$\frac{|f′_α(z)|}{1+|f_α(z)|^2},α∈A$$
>   is uniformly bounded in any compact domain of $D$.

I've found this theorem in p.227, Theorem 17 of Ahlfors' book and I understand this works in meromorphic situation, but have no idea how does it work **in analytic one**.

As in meromorphic case, we can use sphere metrics to prove that there is a sequence converges with respect to sphere distance. But **how to prove it converges to a analytic but not meromorphic function in the analytic situation**?